# Object Instance in C#

Tags: c#, object-reference

Why do I get "Object Reference Not Set to Instance of an Object"

```
protected void GetData()
{
    ...

    id = this.GetTabControl().ID; //<---------here
}

...

protected ASPxPageControl GetTabControl()
{
    return (ASPxPageControl)this.FindControl("DetailTab");
}
```

---------I assume the FindControl is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because `GetTabControl()` is returning `null`. We can't tell *why* without more code though.

Answer (score 1):

`GetTabControl()` must be returning a null reference.